A question regarding Urysohn spaces.
Let $X$ be a topological space, $X$ is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ (also called Urysohn), if given $x, y \in X$ such that $x \neq y$, then exists $A, B$ open sets of $X$ such that $x \in A$, $y \in B$ and $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.
I know that every $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ space is $T_2$, every completely $T_2$ space is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$, and every $T_3$ space is $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$. And, I also know that the respective reciprocals do not hold.
But I would like to ask for further applications of $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ spaces, since I haven't been able to find anything new for myself. More precisely, I am asking if there are any interesting implications that the $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ axiom has, but the implications do not hold for the $T_2$ axiom.

Whether you find it interesting or not is subjective, but there are spaces known as semi-Urysohn spaces or $s$-Urysohn spaces that fulfil what you're asking. A topological space $X$ is called semi-Urysohn if any two distinct points in $X$ can be separated by semi-open sets whose closures are disjoint.

Definition: A set $U$ in $(X,\tau)$ is said to be semi-open if and only if there exists an open set $E$ such that $E \subseteq U \subseteq cl(E)$.

A semi-open set may be open, closed, or both. Try to come up with examples on the real line. There are also many examples of sets that are not semi-open. It's important to note that semi-open sets are not closed under complement or intersection.
From the definition, it's clear that a $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$ space implies semi-Urysohn, since every open set is semi-open. However, Hausdorff ($T_2$) does not necessarily imply semi-Urysohn. A counterexample is the irrational slope topology.
Consider $X = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2  : y \geq 0 \ \text{and} \ x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ and fix some irrational number $\theta$. The irrational slope topology is generated by neighbourhoods of the form $$N_\epsilon((x,y)) = \{(x,y)\} \cup B_\epsilon(x-y/\theta) \cup B_\epsilon(x+y/\theta),$$
where $B_\epsilon(z) := \left\{r\in \mathbb{Q} : |r-z| < \epsilon \right\}$. The name comes from the fact that the lines joining $(x,y)$ to $(x-y/\theta,0)$ and $(x+y/\theta,0)$ have slopes $\pm \theta$.
Try proving that this defines a topology and that $X$ equipped with this topology is $T_2$. However, this space is not semi-Urysohn, which shows that $T_2$ does not imply semi-Urysohn. There are also examples of semi-Urysohn spaces that are not Urysohn. For more details, check the references below.

More on Semi-Urysohn Spaces, Julian Dontchev and Maximilian Ganster
Semi-open Sets, William James Maurice Thomas
Counterexamples in Topology, L.A. Steen and J.A. Seebach, Jr.


Thank you so much for your great answer, Oscar. This wasn't a concept that I was aware of. It is good that I had studied that the irrational slope topology is a space that is Hausdorff but isn't Urysohn before, so the familiarity has allowed me to follow it better.

@Almanzoris Great! Glad you liked the answer :)

I assume that, in order to make $B_\epsilon(z)$ a subset of $X$, you identify $r\in\mathbb Q$ with $(r,0)\in X$.

@Andreas Blass Indeed
